# Using SQL GROUP BY but still need all values (not just MAX value)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to grab multiple results but group to one result and give overall counts on certain categories. When I do the SQL GROUP BY with my attempts I can only get the MAX value. I need the total orderqty of each device.

```
Desktops - 2
Laptops  - 5
```

MSSQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    m.SDDOCO as salesorder, 
    MAX(m.SDPA8) as customerid, 
    MAX(m.SDNXTR) as status, 
    MAX(m.SDSRP1) as device, 
    MAX(m.SDUORG) as orderqty, 
    MAX(a.ABALPH) as customername,
    MAX(d.DEDATE02) as shipbydate,
    CASE WHEN MAX(m.SDSRP1)='DES' THEN MAX(m.SDUORG) ELSE 0 END AS desktops,
    CASE WHEN MAX(m.SDSRP1)='NTB' THEN MAX(m.SDUORG) ELSE 0 END AS notebooks,
    CASE WHEN MAX(m.SDSRP1)='MON' THEN MAX(m.SDUORG) ELSE 0 END AS monitors
FROM $JDE_F4211 m, $JDE_F554211 d, $JDE_F0101 a 
WHERE 
    d.DEDOCO=m.SDDOCO AND 
    d.DEDCTO=m.SDDCTO AND 
    d.DEKCOO=m.SDKCOO AND 
    d.DELNID=m.SDLNID AND 
    m.SDPA8=a.ABAN8 AND 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(m.SDDCTO)) = 'SO' AND 
    (LTRIM(RTRIM(m.SDLNTY)) = 'WC' OR 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(m.SDLNTY)) = 'S') AND
    LTRIM(RTRIM(m.SDMCU)) <> 'RLG' AND 
    m.SDNXTR<980
GROUP BY m.SDDOCO 
ORDER BY m.SDDOCO DESC
```

SQL results without grouping:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [salesorder] => 3238404
            [customerid] => 142578
            [status] => 530
            [device] => NTB
            [orderqty] => 5
            [customername] => CUSTOMER1         
            [shipbydate] => 0
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [salesorder] => 3238404
            [customerid] => 142578
            [status] => 530
            [device] => DES
            [orderqty] => 2
            [customername] => CUSTOMER1         
            [shipbydate] => 0
        )
```

SQL GROUP BY output:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [salesorder] => 3238404
            [customerid] => 142578
            [status] => 530
            [device] => NTB
            [orderqty] => 5
            [customername] => CUSTOMER1        
            [shipbydate] => 0
            [desktops] => 0.0
            [notebooks] => 5
            [monitors] => 0.0
        )
```

This is how I wish my output would show:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you intend:

```
SELECT m.SDDOCO as salesorder, 
       MAX(m.SDPA8) as customerid, 
       MAX(m.SDNXTR) as status, 
       MAX(m.SDSRP1) as device, 
       MAX(m.SDUORG) as orderqty, 
       MAX(a.ABALPH) as customername,
       MAX(d.DEDATE02) as shipbydate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.SDSRP1 = 'DES' THEN m.SDUORG ELSE 0 END) AS desktops,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.SDSRP1 = 'NTB' THEN m.SDUORG ELSE 0 END) AS notebooks,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.SDSRP1 = 'MON' THEN m.SDUORG ELSE 0 END) AS monitors
FROM $JDE_F4211 m JOIN
     $JDE_F554211 d
     ON d.DEDOCO = m.SDDOCO AND 
        d.DEDCTO = m.SDDCTO AND 
        d.DEKCOO = m.SDKCOO AND 
        d.DELNID = m.SDLNID JOIN
     $JDE_F0101 a 
     ON m.SDPA8=a.ABAN8
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(m.SDDCTO)) = 'SO' AND 
      (LTRIM(RTRIM(m.SDLNTY)) = 'WC' OR 
       LTRIM(RTRIM(m.SDLNTY)) = 'S'
      ) AND
      LTRIM(RTRIM(m.SDMCU)) <> 'RLG' AND 
     m.SDNXTR < 980
GROUP BY m.SDDOCO 
ORDER BY m.SDDOCO DESC;
```

A piece of advice:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: As OP want `total orderqty of each device`, IMO the `MAX` should change to `SUM` for `SDUORG`

Comment: @PhamX.Bach . . . I agree.  I used `MAX()` because that is what the OP had in his/her query.

Comment: Thanks - this works perfectly.  Btw.. You have an extra ) in the first SUM(CASE line before ELSE 0 END... causing syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have your desired output in the question for the non-quantity related fields. Using Sum with conditions instead of MAX should help you for your group counts. try this for your select clause

```
SELECT 
m.SDDOCO as salesorder, 
MAX(m.SDPA8) as customerid, 
MAX(m.SDNXTR) as status, 
MAX(m.SDSRP1) as device, 
SUM(m.SDUORG) as orderqty, 
MAX(a.ABALPH) as customername,
MAX(d.DEDATE02) as shipbydate,
SUM(CASE WHEN m.SDSRP1 ='DES' THEN m.SDUORG ELSE 0 END) AS desktops,
SUM(CASE WHEN m.SDSRP1 ='NTB' THEN m.SDUORG ELSE 0 END) AS notebooks,
SUM(CASE WHEN m.SDSRP1 ='MON' THEN m.SDUORG ELSE 0 END) AS monitors
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running as a subquery for each device and then joining the results together on the salesorder and any other necessary fields. This should give you the one line output you seek. Simplified version below:

```
Select a.salesorder, a.desktops, b.notebooks, c.monitors
FROM
(SELECT 
    m.SDDOCO as salesorder,  
    MAX(m.SDUORG) as desktops
FROM Table m
WHERE m.SDSRP1 = 'DES'
GROUP BY m.SDDOCO) a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    m.SDDOCO as salesorder,  
    MAX(m.SDUORG) as notebooks
FROM Table m
WHERE m.SDSRP1 = 'NTB'
GROUP BY m.SDDOCO) b
on a.salesorder = b.salesorder
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    m.SDDOCO as salesorder,  
    MAX(m.SDUORG) as monitors
FROM Table m
WHERE m.SDSRP1 = 'MON'
GROUP BY m.SDDOCO) c
on a.salesorder = c.salesorder
```